# Variable size in 32 bit or 64 bit processor

Tags: assembly, architecture, cpu, bit

¿What are the main differences between 32 and 64 bit processors? I am having some issues to understand it.

Has 32 bit processors variables with a size of 4 Bytes? And has 64 bit processors variables with a size of 8 bytes? I don't knwo if it is correct. If it is, I don't know if this lenghts are the same for all vars stored in the stack.

Thanks!

Comment: Variables can have any size you want, regardless of the CPU architecture.  Variables equal or smaller than the register width are more efficient, but most CPUs can load/store any power-of-2 size up to their bitness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question comes from a buffer overflow book. I read that if 64 bit processor is used instead of 32 bit processor, some buffer overflows couldn't work as expected. Sorry for my first explanation but I refered to vars like EIP, EBP...Is the length of these vars according with the proccesor architecture or your explanation means that also these vars can have different length? Thanks!!

Comment: Those are registers, not high-level-language variables.  Keep reading more about asm.

Comment: The "bitness" of a CPU refers to the max number of bits in their general purpose registers. So a 32 bit microprocessor has 32-bit general purpose registers. As Peter says, you can access any amount of external memory you wish. You would usually manipulate that memory using these registers so you'd be often accessing the memory 32 bits at a time.

Comment: Thanks both! There was an answer posted by "cadanicu" or some name like that but now I can't see it. It was so clearly so I don't know why this answer was deleted...

Comment: @cadaniluk, could you post again your answer? Thanks"!